# my problem is I don't know if my GPU is active or not can anyone tell what is happening?

Tags: drivers, nvidia, graphics, nvidia-geforce

Additional driver is not showing any Nvidia driver and Nvidia-smi is giving this
[image: Nvidia-smi result] I'm using ubuntu 22.04

Comment: please do not add images of text. copy/paste text into the question That way people that sear ch for the text in your image will find this question.

Comment: Please state the version of Ubuntu you are using.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see any problems. The adapter is working and a proprietary driver installed.

You can also check is the Nvidia GPU rendering is used by running:

```
glxinfo | grep OpenGL
```